# Adding hours, minutes, seconds to current time

Tags: go, time

How do I add hours, minutes, and seconds (defined as ints) to the current time, similar to `AddDate`?

```
timein := time.Now().Local().AddDate(Hours, Mins, Sec)
```

but with hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate

AddDate() function added years, months and days to time

Answer (score 221, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is

```
timein := time.Now().Local().Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(Hours) +
                                 time.Minute * time.Duration(Mins) +
                                 time.Second * time.Duration(Sec))
```

Comment: what is that := symbol?

Comment: Syntactic sugar for declaring and assigning a variable at the same time. Replaces var timein time.Time followed by timein = ...

Comment: Simplified: `timein := time.Now().Add(time.Hour * hours + time.Minute * mins + time.Second * sec)`

Answer (score 7):

**This answer is outdated. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40589596/3789550).**

---

`AddDate` takes (and adds) year, month, day as parameters, not hour, minute, second.

From https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate:

```
func (t Time) AddDate(years int, months int, days int) Time
```

Comment: This no longer answers the question. (I can see how it might have been an answer for the first version, before edits).